# What's the difference of a PWA vs. Safari website?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, progressive-web-apps

I am wondering what is the difference between a website in Safari vs. a progressive web app (when you click in Safari -> Share -> Add to homescreen).

As an example, this website

https://beta.play.geforcenow.com/

leads inside Safari to a website that shows the steps to create a PWA, but once you open this freshly created PWA it leads you to a different website.

**What's the mechanism used there? Is this a different user agent?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick used here is `window.navigator.standalone`. To trick it simply override it like this on page load

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'standalone', {get:function(){return true;}});
```